# why does it works even though Model name is plural on Laravel?

Tags: php, database, laravel, model, relation

I am new at Laravel.

As I am studying Laravel I noticed that ALL `Model` I made is named by the plural but it works properly.

I am wondering how can it happen because I read documents after I noticed that and it says like, "Model should be named by the singular.".

Can anyone explain how it works??

P.S. There is no mention `$table` in those Model.

***I am so sorry I wanted to say "singular" not "syllable".***

Comment: Refer this link might be helpful for you

Comment: @AnkurTiwari Thanks but you maybe forgot leaving the link I think :)

Comment: Opps, Sorry https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/laravel-table-names-are-plural-by-default?page=1

Comment: @AnkurTiwari Thanks! I read and I would have to say that I knew already that the plural table is named by default. What I want to know is why is it okay to name Model as plural but really thanks for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General convention of laravel is using a singular name for a model and a plural name for a table. Note that you can change the associated table name by using `protected $table = 'yourTableName';` in your model. I personally think setting it manually is a good practice.

I can't explain how it gets the associated table name as it will be an essay(also I am not sure I will be able to explain properly) but I can send you to the right direction.

As laravel is open source you can actually peak under the hood and see how it works. You can go to `framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php` or see it [online](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php) to see the associate functions. You will see the `getTable` function which will return the table name. But it uses another function. So you need to see what is in that function.

After a few digging you will see that laravel actually uses a different library to help getting the project name. It uses [inflector](https://github.com/doctrine/inflector). You can browse a bit about it to understand how it gets the plural name. There you can find the underlying code and rules etc to understand how it works.

Comment: Thank you for answering!
I have a question.
Are those why the Models which is named as plural works even though it is supposed to be named as singular?

Comment: The pluralizer function of the inflector library returns the same table name if the model name is in plural. However, the opposite won't work. If you have both the table and model name in singular it won't work by default. You need to explicitly set the relation between them.